# move node from second to first

Tags: javascript

Just want a function that move second node to be a first node.But it not working, any suggestion?

```
 var node = document.getElementById("ir");
    var cx = node.childNodes[1];
    function der(){
    node.insertBefore(cx,node.firstChild);
}
```

fullcode:

```
<div id="ir">
<p id="ie">test</p>
<img src="test.gif">
</div>

<script type="text/Javascript">
var node = document.getElementById("ir");
img.setAttribute("onclick","der()");
var cx = node.childNodes[1];
function der(){
        node.insertBefore(cx,node.previousSibling);
}
```

Comment: This code is incomplete, can you fix it? (open brace in function der()). Also state the reason you want to change the order, for example for visual effect. Include the code of the object you are attempting to manipulate if that is available.

Comment: _“But it not working, any suggestion?”_ – Suggestion: Please learn that “does not work” is not a valid problem description.

Comment: enix CBroe is not correct in this case, your question is clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit slow today, but I think your use of  previousSibling is wrong. I think it should relate to the child node cx not the parent node .. so you should be using cx.previousSibling not node.previousSibling - I've edited mt previous example to remove my original dumb response ...  try this ...

```
<div id="ir">
<p id="ie">test</p>
<img src="test.gif">
</div>

<script type="text/Javascript">
var node = document.getElementById("ir");
img.setAttribute("onclick","der()");
var cx = node.childNodes[1];
function der(){
    node.insertBefore(cx,cx.previousSibling);
}
```

Two Days Later Edit !!! ....
Of course the example I gave above will not swap the P element and the image because the image's true previousSibling is a newline character between the /P tag closure and the image. More importantly from a coding perspective, it won't work because there isn't an object called 'img' defined anywhere ... so I offer this as a working alternative :

```
<script>
function swapDivs(obj) {
  if(obj.previousSibling){ // if it's null, then it's already the first element //
    obj.parentNode.insertBefore(obj, obj.previousSibling);
  }
}
</script>

<div id="ir">
  <p id="ie">test</p><img src="http://i2.ifrm.com/4639/142/emo/drool.gif" onclick="swapDivs(this);" />
</div>
```

It  doesn't address the newline issue, I just reformatted the HTML.

However, it does resolve the img issue, and provides a generic way of adding the function to any clickable DOM object without having to customise the function.

I'll leave it to you to work out how to get over the problem with the newline/whitespace sibling, but it shouldn't be to difficult. Here's the fiddle to play with if you want to test your attempts ... http://jsfiddle.net/radiotrib/ps9XZ/

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/joeframbach/JSZPy/

The issue with the html in that fiddle is the spaces. `childNodes[0]` matches the first set of spaces, and `childNodes[1]` matches the first element. Perhaps this is your issue.

```
<div id="ir">
    <p>First</p>
    <p>Second</p>
</div>

var node = document.getElementById("ir");
var first = node.childNodes[1];
var second = node.childNodes[3];
node.insertBefore(second,first);
```

Comment: I recommend using jQuery to manipulate elements in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an answer but i recommend doing something like:

```
var node = document.getElementById("ir");
var childs = node.getElementsByTagName("div");
var cx = childs[1];

function der()
{
    node.removeChild(cx);
    node.insertBefore(cx, childs[0]);
}

der();
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you not to put spaces or breaklines when working with childnodes, because they are considering like child of text type. I hope this code will help you:
Javascript code:

```
function change(){
    var parent = document.getElementById("ir");
    var img = parent.childNodes[1];
    parent.removeChild(img);
    parent.insertBefore(img, parent.firstChild);
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="ir"><p id="ie">test</p><img src="test.gif"></div>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```